# Loading numpy array from http response without saving a file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a bunch of files containing numpy arrays at some url (e.g., `https://my_url/my_np_file.npy`) and I am trying to load them in my computer.

If I download the file manually, I can properly load the numpy array using `np.load('file_path')`. If I take the url reponse (using the code below), save the content to a file and then use `np.load()`, it also works.

```
response, content = http.request('https://my_url/my_np_file.npy')
```

If I try to load the array from the content string, I get the error bellow. This is likely because the `np.load` is interpreting the string input as a name for the file, rather than the data itself.

> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line
>   370, in load
>       fid = open(file, "rb") TypeError: file() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str

Is there any way to load the array without having to save a file?

Answer (score 13):

You are missing `io.BytesIO` to make the string appear like a file object to `np.load`!

The following is what you're looking for:

```
import requests
import io

response = requests.get('https://my_url/my_np_file.npy')
response.raise_for_status()
data = np.load(io.BytesIO(response.content))  # Works!
```

Answer (score 0):

I just worked out a workaround using `shutil`

```
import requests
import shutil
response = requests.get('http://path/to/test.npy', stream=True)

with open('haha.npy', 'wb') as fin:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, fin)

np.load('haha.npy') # Works!
```

This will first download the file itself though, but in an automatic fashion.

Answer (score -1):

Can you add an example of the HTTP response? (from `https://my_url/my_np_file.npy`)

Maybe you could try [`np.fromstring`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) after you retrieve the web response.

This is an example from the above reference.

```
>>> np.fromstring('1 2', dtype=int, sep=' ')
array([1, 2])
>>> np.fromstring('1, 2', dtype=int, sep=',')
array([1, 2])
```